# Object to return property?

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

I have a class called Type:

```
class Type { ... }
```

Which has a property named `$value`:

```
class Type {
    protected $value;

    //More code here...
}
```

I wish that when I attempt to use a function, when I pass the object, the value of `$obj->value` will be passed. For example:

```
$obj = new Type("value");
echo $obj; //Desired output: value
```

I've tried many things, and searched everywhere, but I can't seem to find this one. Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance. :)

**EDIT:** Maybe you misunderstood (or narrowed) my question a bit. I want it for all value types, not just the string ones, including `int` `float` and `boolean`

```
$obj = new Type(true);
echo !$obj; //Desired output: false

$obj2 = new Type(9);
echo ($obj + 1); //Desired output: 10
```

Comment: Try with the __toString() magic method :)

Comment: In what kind of function would you to use that ? For everyting connected to text, you could always use the magic method toString.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: [Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.magic.php)

```
class Type {
  public function __toString() {
    return (string)$this->value;
  }
}
```

If your usage of the object won't trigger the *magic* you can allways use:

```
$someVar = (string)$obj;
```

**Update**:

Beyond strings or arrays (see [ArrayAccess interface](http://php.net/manual/class.arrayaccess.php)), it's, at the moment, not possible to have php handle objects like predefined [data types](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.php).

Comment: Almost there, but I want it to work for all types, (otherwise the class would be called `String` now would it? :P) I've edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin If you have a look at the link above, you'll see that what you're trying to achieve is not possible with php at the moment.

Comment: Please add that to the answer and I will accept it as correct :) Thank you.